# from mysql to mongodb - designing collections

Tags: mysql, database-design, mongodb

I'm curious to get peoples opinions on they would design this collection scheme.

I want to try using mongodb for an app (as i have been using mysql for the past 8 years)

I will give a relational table schema first.

Tables

```
users
user_friends
user_notifications

articles
article_categories
article_participants

comments
```

If I were to implement that table structure into mongodb, would this be the right way to define my collections:

```
users => array
{
    _id
    email,
    password,
    name,
    ...
    user_friend => array{
        _user_id,
        date_created
    }
    user_notifications => array{
        _notification_id
    }
    my_articles =>array{
        _article_id
    }
}

article
{
    _id,
    content_,
    date_created,
    ...,
    article_category => array{
        _category_id
    }
    article_participants = array{
        _user_id
    } 
    comments=>array{
        _user_id
        name,
        comment,
        date
    }
}

categories
{
    _id,
    _user_id
    name
    comments=>array{
        _user_id
        name,
        comment,
        date
    }
}
```

Please feel to comment or explain how you would organize your collections. Any help is much appreciated.

As well, should i even be using mongodb for this type of application? (a social blog sharing app)

Answer (score 1):

my opinion is  the best way is to use value-object like to embed object of entity object.

check this [link for more details](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design)

Value Object: An object that contains attributes but has no conceptual identity. They should be treated as immutable.

Example: When people exchange dollar bills, they generally do not distinguish between each unique bill; they only are concerned about the face value of the dollar bill. In this context, dollar bills are value objects. However, the Federal Reserve may be concerned about each unique bill; in this context each bill would be an entity.

Answer (score 0):

Mongodb will be an excellent tool for such an application.

In MongoDB, Embedding is much more efficient than referencing using extra tables.

For more information, you can look into this link **http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Schema+Design**